# Why is 'undefined' returned when comparing an function argument to a string from a function?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I created cpuPlay to call either rock, paper, or scissors, whenever a random number between 0-2 is called. This function works properly, but **rps()** is the function that I can't seem to build properly after 3 days of doing this. No matter how I build this, it seems I keep on getting one of four answers when I call rps(). The answers I get are either **'rock','paper','scissors','undefined'**.

Before I thought it was because I used .toLowerCase() on playerChoice, but either way, this function has been giving the same results. If you keep on running rps('paper'), it eventually shows. I'm not sure how I should go any further with this problem, or maybe I'm not supposed to be able to compare.  I don't even know anymore.

```
function cpuPlay(){
    let numberGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

  if (numberGen === 0){
    return 'rock'
  }
  if (numberGen === 1){
    return 'paper'
  }
  if (numberGen === 2){
    return 'scissors'
  }
}
// cpuPlay()

function rps(playersChoice){
  if(playersChoice == 'paper' && cpuPlay() == 'rock'){
    console.log('rock')
  } else if (playersChoice == 'paper' && cpuPlay() == 'paper'){
    console.log('paper')
  } else if (playersChoice == 'paper' &&  cpuPlay() == 'scissors'){
    console.log('scissors');
  }
}
rps('paper')
```

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me with my problem. It seems that the problem was comparing the function itself rather than assigning it to its own variable; Again, thanks for the help with this problem.

Comment: Jermaine, please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site and how to follow up when you receive answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `cpuPlay()` in each expression so it is possible that every conditional fails, because `cpuPlay()` value is changing, you can try this:

```js
function cpuPlay(){
    let numberGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

  if (numberGen === 0){
    return 'rock'
  }
  if (numberGen === 1){
    return 'paper'
  }
  if (numberGen === 2){
    return 'scissors'
  }
}

function rps(playersChoice){
  let currentCpuPlay = cpuPlay()
  if(playersChoice == 'paper' && currentCpuPlay == 'rock'){
    console.log('rock')
  } else if (playersChoice == 'paper' && currentCpuPlay == 'paper'){
    console.log('paper')
  } else if (playersChoice == 'paper' &&  currentCpuPlay == 'scissors'){
    console.log('scissors');
  }
}
rps('paper')
```

Answer (score 1):

`cpuPlay()` generates a random value **every time you call it**.

You are generating a random value and comparing it to `rock`. Then you generate **a new** random value and compare it to `paper`. Then you generate a **third** random value and compare it to `scissors`.

You should generate the CPU player's response **once**, at the top of the comparison function and then compare that value each time.

```
function rps(playersChoice){
    const cpuChoice = cpuPlay();
    if(playersChoice == 'paper' && cpuChoice == 'rock'){
```

Answer (score 0):

the `cpuPlay()` is returning random results at every if statement

so when in the first `if` and the result is not rock, it will jump to next statement again, then but at the second `if`, the `cpuPlay()` is returning different results, so end up your function has a chance to have no results.

```js
function rps(playersChoice){
  let cpuRoll = cpuPlay(); // only random once per game
  if(playersChoice == 'paper' && cpuRoll == 'rock'){
    console.log('rock')
  } else if (playersChoice == 'paper' && cpuRoll == 'paper'){
    console.log('paper')
  } else if (playersChoice == 'paper' &&  cpuRoll == 'scissors'){
    console.log('scissors');
  }
}
```